# Argument of type '(number | null)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to ts and have just started migrating my app from js to ts.
first function - calcAvg, takes an array of numbers and returns their average.
second function - takes a list of objects. each object has daily statistics (see DailyData interface).
TS marks calcAvg(marginArray) as an error - "Argument of type '(number | null)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'.
Type 'number | null' is not assignable to type 'number'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2345)
const marginRevArray: (number | null)[]"

Before calcAvg , I am checking the array for nulls and if there is one or more nulls values I don't calculate the average.

Any ideas what am I missing here?
Thanks!

*** see code below

```
interface DailyData {
  id: number
  cost: number
  margin: number

}
const calcAvg = (dataList: number[]) => {
  const reducer = (accumulator: number, curr: number) => accumulator + curr;
  const dataSum = dataList.reduce(reducer, 0);
  return dataSum / dataList.length;
};


const avgMargin = (dailyData: DailyData[]) => {
  const marginArray = dailyData.map((obj: DailyData) => obj.cost > 0 ? obj.margin/obj.cost: null);
  if (marginArray.some((el: number|null) => el=== null)) {
    //if the array has null values don't calculate
    return 'no data';
  }
  return calcAvg(marginArray);
};
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mMVQZW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: You'll have to use type inferrence, typescript is just not smart enough to understand that marginArray doesn't contain any nulls. So the last line should be `return calcAvg(marginArray as number[]);`

Comment: Check if there are some values that `<= 0` first and return if so, otherwise - map.

Comment: If you can refactor to use `every` instead of `some`, then you can annotate to use it as a type guard [like this](https://tsplay.dev/w6XaYm).  Do you want me to write up an answer? Let me know. Either way, you should fix the typos in your question code.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the correction, you're right that I didn't use the correct term (I brainfarted). But the correct term is actually  "assertion". Casting implies that the data is changed in runtime (or at least some information about how the runtime should interpret the data). This doesn't happen in typescript since the javascript isn't changed.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, please make that an answer!

Comment: @Jclaz: my bad , edited my code, should be fine now :)

Comment: @ShamPooSham  yes ! that worked , thank you !!

Comment: @Limor That's good! But don't get too comfortable with using type assertions. Types are there to help you not make mistakes, and with type assertions you're telling the type system "don't worry, I know what I'm doing". It can easily be abused to a point where the type system won't be of any help. In this case it's fine though.

Comment: @jcalz what do you mean by "annotate to use it as a type guard"?

Comment: @jered I mean `(el: number | null): el is number => el !== null`, which is seen as a type guard function, as opposed to `(el: number | null) => el !== null`, which is not.  The difference is the return type predicate annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TypeScript standard library call signature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/5e09e86612f775785137b74482ba77764e22246e/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1349) for [`Array`'s `some()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) looks like

```
interface Array<T> {
  some(
    predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => unknown, 
    thisArg?: any
  ): boolean;
}
```

which means that when you call `marginArray.some(el => el === null)`, all the compiler knows is that this will return a `boolean`.  It has no idea that this should have any implication whatsoever for the type of `marginArray`.  So the type of `marginArray` is still `(number | null)[]` if the call returns `true`, and so the compiler balks at

```
calcAvg(marginArray) // error! marginArray might have nulls in it, I think
```

If you want to get rid of the error **without refactoring**, you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).  Type assertions are meant for situations like this where you, the developer, know more about the type a value will have than the compiler can figure out.  If you are sure that `marginArray` will be a `number[]` by the time you call `calcAvg()`, then you can just tell the compiler that:

```
calcAvg(marginArray as number[]); // okay
```

This works, but is not a magic cure-all; by using a type assertion you are taking the responsibility onto yourself for its accuracy.  The compiler doesn't know if `marginArray` has `null`s in it or not; it just believes you when you tell it.  If you accidentally lie to the compiler, it won't catch it:

```
if (marginArray.some(el => el !== null)) { //  wrong check
  return 'no data';
}
return calcAvg(marginArray as number[]); // still no error
```

So you should double and triple check whenever you make a type assertion that you're doing it right.

---

On the other hand, if you don't mind some **mild refactoring**, you can switch from `some()` to [`Array`'s `every()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), whose [standard library typings includes the following call signature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/5e09e86612f775785137b74482ba77764e22246e/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1331):

```
interface Array<T> {
  every<S extends T>(
    predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => value is S, 
    thisArg?: any
  ): this is S[];
}
```

This says that if you pass a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) in as `predicate` which can [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type of the array elements, then `every()` can itself be used as a user-defined type guard function which can narrow the type of the whole array.  So if `predicate` is annotated so that a `true` return value implies that `value` is `number` and not `null`, then a `true` return value from `every()` will tell the compiler that the whole array is a `number[]`:

```
if (!marginArray.every((el: number | null): el is number => el !== null)) {
  return 'no data';
}
return calcAvg(marginArray); // okay
```

See how the callback function has been annotated to be of type `(el: number | null) => el is number`?  Now the compiler understands that if `calcAvg()` is reached, then `marginArray` is a `number[]`.

This is probably the closest you can get to type safety.  I say "closest" because the act of annotating a function as a user-defined type guard is still the developer telling the compiler something it can't figure out.  It would be nice if `el => el !== null` would automatically be *inferred* as a type guard, but it's not.  There's at least one open feature request about this: see [microsoft/TypeScript#38390](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38390).  So you can still make the same kind of mistake as above and the compiler won't catch it:

```
if (!marginArray.every((el: number | null): el is number => el === null)) { // 
  return 'no data';
}
```

At least in the refactored version, though, the scope of potential mistakes is narrower.  You have to write `el is number` right next to where you write `el !== null`, whereas the original version has you writing `marinArray as number[]` farther away from where the relevant check is taking place.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJ2AGwJ7rHZAbwFgAoZZYAEwC5kQBXAWwCNoyKEB7AZzDsat25ZEzhQA5qAHM2UMmQC+ZbiD7IEcTAgCCANwnIAvMgAUVOPgAywPjKFQA2gF0AlMYB8RDhq5qwyFAQVAxIUMZmiAjMDJiWXFD2cgA0GgxQifSy0O5GXlExcWAJyADUaRkA3D6q6hb4AMrMEfVwNnwAdEEhSKbdodCpAAyu1SJBYOkgyK1NTMgA9DOWbbZgHZgQIBJgABZjimMqfupwBgCy4lIgAPJQwIYm5hg4eHB06Fi4Ky65XiQiWoBMSSUA6DJwbAtF7ffAdMQAB1Mpi4LAAVh8YW8-shUWiOtx1F4hsgAPy49Hwq6gRYU-GEgIyTCYUY+YAwMwg67gqCQjo8LhMCCmCCYTzIUXGIwmRjM1zuAEUCgTKbIADkIC4y3warGFGU4wgkyg0002n0ElMXLBEKhcB4WQcvwOR1IQOQZwkl1Bty4CIdTwsXzemODPzc4sVvn8ompIB5kOhYbhiOReNDrxWOLxBN4AWJZLpVJ9tJzDOQTJZesoHKtcYT2H5guFkryErFAEJpVk5QrFksuH6eMAID5lUbVRqta1dT4DePjaatLoDHWfQ2PQ7BHJnUpXccY57vdcIs9k+80Fjwzio+7rfHbUnMym4EiUeiM7C4NnKeWC6SxyLe9S1-PMKx7Ks2VrDt7wbDoID0aBsGRUUkmgZAAB8INcOhJVsR05HFSUuxlWIWQVQCVRNdVNW1OBZxEedAgnaizRXS1YNtUZ+1xABrSE9wUN0TgCI84xuIcdAkDBpkDK98E-N5fkjGoRNjddHxMINnzgKk33TS9zx-ekwP-QCc2AgdQPUStWREdkzBg+tbXgxCoGQkVMDQ8IsNlFlcLFfDt3QttW27Pz5SIHjAF4NwBQPcoljpinOiGP1HwqKXc1V043lsG4hYB347A9yAA)